# How can I display an image using data of Vue which is String and from backend?

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend

My project saves users' profile images path in the database as varchar which is transfer into String in the backend and use JSON to send it to the frontend. How can I use this string to display an image by Vue?

Here you can see:
[Image URL can be received as a "string" by frontend correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgCCB.png)

I have tried for

```
<img class="user-profile-image" v-bind:src=userProfileImagePath>
<img class="user-profile-image" :src=userProfileImagePath>
<img class="user-profile-image" src=userProfileImagePath>
<img class="user-profile-image" src="userProfileImagePath">
```

But they all didn't work. How can I do?

Comment: Does it log any errors?

Comment: Please show the rest of the component template surrounding the `<img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    imageUri: ""
  },
  methods: {
    loadIcon() {
      // You might want to load your data here
      this.imageUri = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27"
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadIcon();
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img v-bind:src="imageUri" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse(image_string_path_here) then use this parse link in image